# Error while parsing XML using XMLPullParser in android?

Tags: android-xml, xmlpullparser

I'm getting error while paring xml in android using XMLPullParser if the text contains special character like &. How can I solve this?

Comment: Btw: If you like an answer to the questions you ask, you can mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 0):

`&` is a special character in XML, marking the start of an entity e.g. `&amp;` for an Ampersand -- consider it as a "macro"-definition.

If the parser sees this, it tries to replace it with the real value (of the "macro").

Now to be able to do so, it needs to know the definitions, which can e.g. come from a DTD or a schema that defines those. Or also from the XML itself, which defines them before first use.

See here for an example of an XML file that defines such an entity at the top and uses it later: https://git.fedorahosted.org/cgit/rhq/rhq.git/tree/modules/plugins/jboss-as-5/src/main/resources/META-INF/rhq-plugin.xml?id=RHQ_4_9_0 -- this entity "managedObjectMetrics" on line 5 is then later used on line 1325 and others.

Comment: isn't there a way to replace all '&' in text once we set xml data to pullparser?

Comment: What would you expect to get when replacing the `&` in `&amp;` - the result is non-sense

Comment: Link is no longer valid.